# Old PC unable to boot windows installation from USB

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I have made a bootable USB with Windows XP installation using Rufus. The USB boots normally on newer PCs, but I have 2 older PCs that are unable to boot from it.

When I select it as the boot device, I'm getting "A disk read error has occurred" message and it doesn't boot at all.

I have tried various different settings in bios, but I wasn't able to find a solution. There aren't many settings related to USB.

Comment: It is likely that the drivers for your chipset are missing in windows and as such it can't detect your harddisk. During the setup, you should be able to press F6 and use a driverdisk with the correct drivers you can download. Do you get into a setup?

Comment: No, it doesn't boot at all. I just get this message.

Comment: Is your usb stick a USB 3.0 stick, and does your computer support the version of USB that the stick uses? Also, have you tried the ports on the back of the pc? Older ones usually only have newer ports directly on the motherboard while the chassis usually are older.

Comment: It is a USB 3.0 stick, but I have also tried with a 2.0 stick and got the same results. I have also tried all of the ports on the back.